# PhantomJS colors module "Can't find variable: process"

Tags: node.js, colors, npm, phantomjs

I have installed the colors module using:

```
npm install colors
```

I also have copied 'colors.js-master' to my desktop.
Whenever I try to "require" 'colors' or even point to the index/colors file on my desktop, it says:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process
:26
```

Here is the current code I am using that is pointing to the one on my desktop:

```
var colors = require('C:/Users/KidsRoom/Desktop/colors/lib/index');
console.log("test".yellow);
```

I've also tried globally installing colors with:

```
npm install -g colors
```

And then I tried doing:

```
var colors = require('colors');
console.log("test".yellow)
```

Comment: Hello? Does bumping do anything?

Comment: I am not sure but afaik PhantomJS does not allow you to require node modules

Comment: Then how would I make it work? Just do: console.log("test".yellow)? EDIT: It returns 'undefined' when I do so.

Comment: Because the module was not loaded you can also write console.log("test".RobRob) and it will return undefined

Comment: `process` is a node environment variable - phantomjs doesnt have it and the color module probably needs it

Comment: I got it now by installing process into the same directory, but now it gives me THIS error: 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating process.argv') :26